# Symfony setlocale()

Tags: php, symfony

I want to use setlocale() to get translated months in my whole app. In which file should I put the usage of this function?

My code for now:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pl_PL.utf8');
$date = ucfirst(strftime('%B %Y'));
```

More general question: In Symfony, where should I put some globally evaluated scripts?

EDIT:

I need this in all environments and in console too, so putting it into `app_dev.php` or Request listener is not my case.

Configuring Apache locally would not solve the problem because I use different configurations on different machines (Apache/nginx).

Putting it into AppKernel didn't work, for now it sits in `app/autoload.php`, but I believe there is a better place for it.

Answer (score 2):

best practice would be to configure apache local,

but you can put this in /app/AppKernel.php

Comment: does it solve your problem? if so, please accept my answer.

Comment: Putting it into AppKernel didn't work, for now it sits in app/autoload.php, but I believe there is a better place for it.

Comment: Configuring Apache locally is not the best in my case because I use different configurations on different machines (Apache/nginx).